# Get Registry Values

Tags: c#, vb.net, registry, regedit

I already figured out how to get the registrykeys, what I am now stucking at is how to get registryvalues of a specific path?

```
Private Sub ListRegistryKeys(ByVal RegistryHive As String, ByVal RegistryPath As String)
    Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    Select Case RegistryHive
        Case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" : key = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" : key = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" : key = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" : key = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_USERS" : key = My.Computer.Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Unknow Registry Hive.")
    End Select
    For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
        ListView2.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thats what I use to get the registrykeys.
Now I like to get the same one for registryvalues, by specifying the Registryhive and the path to the key in the header.
I want the 3 properties of the registryvalues found.

[image: Registry Values in Regedit]

That means

1) Valuename
2) Valuetype
3) Data of the value

How can I modify the sample from above to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, You'd like to get the values in the path and write them out in a list view, similar to the screenshot you took of the registry editor.  You can modify the sample code you provided as follows:

```
Private Sub ListRegistryKeys(ByVal RegistryHive As String, ByVal RegistryPath As String)
    Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
   
    Select Case RegistryHive
        Case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" : key = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" : key = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" : key = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" : key = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case "HKEY_USERS" : key = My.Computer.Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Unknow Registry Hive.")
    End Select

    key.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)

    For Each v In key.GetValueNames()
        Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = ListView2.Items.Add(v)
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(subKey.GetValue(v))
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(subKey.GetValueKind(v).ToString())
    Next

End Sub
```

I call the [OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the RegistryKey containing the selected hive using the path provided.  Then I loop through all of the values, creating a list view item for each value.  The sub-items contain the value and type respectively.

Please note that this is not complete.  You will want to check that the registry path exists or trap an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this throws me a NullReferenceException: http://puu.sh/7hJVC/0524446c2d.png

Comment: And the path definitly exists, and there are also RegistryVlaues inside, nevertheless,it throws me that error.

Comment: Sorry nexno, I fixed my answer.  The OpenSubKey is returning nothing for me as well, but it seems to open the subkey on the key object anyway.

Comment: Hello, again thank you for your effort to try help me :) But unfortunly its still not working for me, it throws the same exception, I made a screenshot: http://puu.sh/7hMo1/bef2589181.png  Do you have an idea why is that? I checked the following: Registrypath does exist: yes! Registrykey has values: yes! I am really confused why it still won't work. hmmm...

Comment: In your latest screenshot you still have subKey = key.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath).  Remove: subKey = .  Next, change For each v in subKey.GetValueNames() to For each v in key.GetValueNames().  Make sure your code looks exactly like what I have above.